# Android login using jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

> activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url = "http://aluno.cefsa.edu.br/Login/Login";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Title().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    String title;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Portal CEFSA");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            org.jsoup.Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("aluno.cefsa.edu.br/login")
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            TextView txt_senha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_senha);
            TextView txt_ra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_ra);


            String usuario = txt_ra.toString();
            String senha = txt_senha.toString();

            Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.POST)
                    .data("Usuario", usuario.trim())
                    .data("Senha", senha.trim())
                    .data("go", "")
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Get the html document title
            title = document.title();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {



        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txt_teste = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_teste);
        txt_teste.setText(title);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context="com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_logo"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="RA:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="Senha:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9609375" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_teste"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Logcat

```
10/02 12:34:14: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android 
arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android 
arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk 
C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Curso android arquivos\TMedias\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.destudios.tmedias/com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 2855 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.destudios.tmedias-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa64f3320: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=27KB, data=31KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=31KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.destudios.tmedias, PID: 2855
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: aluno.cefsa.edu.br/login
                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:101)
                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:43)
                  at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
                  at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$Title.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:51)
                  at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$Title.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:34)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
               Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: aluno.cefsa.edu.br/login
                  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:589)
                  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
                  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:99)
                  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:43) 
                  at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73) 
                  at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$Title.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:51) 
                  at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$Title.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:34) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)

             [ 10-02 15:34:47.296  1647: 3330 D/         ]
             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9a3b0780, tid 3330


             [ 10-02 15:34:47.296  1647: 3330 W/         ]
             Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x98fa7f00 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0x98f0be30
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa64f3320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa649d870)
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity has leaked window DecorView@d25a20b[Portal CEFSA] that was originally added here
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
                 at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$Title.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:44)
                 at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)
                 at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)
                 at com.destudios.tmedias.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:29)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                 at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Application terminated.
```

I have researched many things about jsoup, examples and everything, but I can not log in to this [site](http://aluno.cefsa.edu.br/).

I created an app as a login screen but I do not know how to do the post from my app to the site and get the page to where it is redirected

When I click on it it sends a request to "aluno.cefsa.edu.br/Login/Login" through a post

Could someone help me make the application request from the app to the site

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Okay, I put my code, but it's probably all wrong.

Comment: Why do you send "error_return_url" and "mid" at your `POST` request? It should be "Usuario", "Senha" and "go". The value of "go" is blank, so send it like this = .data("go", ""). And why do you send a second `GET` request after the `POST`?

Comment: I put it as it said, it's updated up there, but it still does not work, when I click the button the app closes

Comment: The app closes, then look at the logcat to figure out why. Copy it into the question please

Comment: It's updated up there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: aluno.cefsa.edu.br/login
```

No protocol set, you must add http:// or https:// to your url

Comment: But I do not know if he is logged in and how do I get information from the next page, could you help me?

Comment: Do open another question for that and accept my answer if it solved your problem. Anyway.. you need to parse the result  from the request and save the result (as Login SUCCESS else fail with message)